# Ace editor throwing infinite loop errors when setting highlight rules of regular expression ending with '|' (pipe char)

Tags: ace-editor

Ace editor is throwing infinite loop errors when setting highlight rules with regular expressions ending with '|' . Eg : "ab|cd|". This is not highlighting all valid matches. Throws below errors repeatedly on console.

```
ace.js:1 Error: infinite loop with in ace tokenizer
    at o.s [as reportError] (ace.js:1)
    at o.getLineTokens (ace.js:1)
    at o.$tokenizeRow (ace.js:1)
    at o.getTokens (ace.js:1)
    at f.getTokens (ace.js:1)
    at a.$renderLine (ace.js:1)
    at a.update (ace.js:1)
    at p.$renderChanges (ace.js:1)
    at ace.js:1
s @ ace.js:1
getLineTokens @ ace.js:1
$tokenizeRow @ ace.js:1
getTokens @ ace.js:1
getTokens @ ace.js:1
$renderLine @ ace.js:1
update @ ace.js:1
$renderChanges @ ace.js:1
(anonymous) @ ace.js:1
requestAnimationFrame (async)
schedule @ ace.js:1
onChangeNewLineMode @ ace.js:1
n._signal @ ace.js:1
$detectNewLine @ ace.js:1
insert @ ace.js:1
insert @ ace.js:1
insert @ ace.js:1
exec @ ace.js:1
(anonymous) @ ace.js:1
n._emit.n._dispatchEvent @ ace.js:1
exec @ ace.js:1
$callKeyboardHandlers @ ace.js:1
onTextInput @ ace.js:1
onTextInput @ ace.js:1
R @ ace.js:1
E @ ace.js:1
16:44:16.379 ace.js:1 Uncaught Error: infinite loop with in ace tokenizer
    at o.s [as reportError] (ace.js:1)
    at o.getLineTokens (ace.js:1)
    at o.$tokenizeRow (ace.js:1)
    at o.getTokens (ace.js:1)
    at f.getTokens (ace.js:1)
    at a.$renderLine (ace.js:1)
    at a.update (ace.js:1)
    at p.$renderChanges (ace.js:1)
    at ace.js:1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This sounds like it might be an application bug that you would report to the ace editor developers.  Have you checked with them to see if there is already an existing bug report and possibly even a fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with ace but with highlight rules. The regexp `/ab|cd|/` matches the empty string, if that is intentional, the highlight rules must switch to another state with different regexps, otherwise they tell tokenizer to apply the same regex at the same place without advancing the position of the match. Ace detects that following the rule would lead to infinite loop, and reports an error.

If you want to match the literal `|` escape it: `"ab|cd\\|"` or `/ab|cd\|/`